# How to list all indexes of a table with their corresponding size in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

I can view the total size of all indexes in a table with

`SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size('table_name'));`

and the size of a specific index with:

`select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('index_name'));`,

but I would like to retrieve a list with size information for each index of the table separately *(a list of index sizes with the corresponding index name they belong to)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [pg_indexes.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-indexes.html)

```
select indexname, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexname::regclass)) as size
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'my_table';
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\di+` psql command:

```
postgres=> \di+ schema.*
                           List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  | Owner | Table  | Persistence |  Size  | Description
--------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------+--------+-------------
 schema | index1 | index | owner | table1 | permanent   | 139 MB |
 schema | index2 | index | owner | table1 | permanent   | 77 MB  |
 schema | index3 | index | owner | table1 | permanent   | 73 MB  |
 schema | index4 | index | owner | table1 | permanent   | 38 MB  |
(4 rows)
```